# Create MultiPolygon from Dataframe column

Tags: python, geopandas, multi-polygon

I have a dataframe with a column called `geo_shape`, for each row in this column data is in the format `str` with the following structure:

`{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-99.1634043186724,19.3929362021363],[-99.1633935829153,19.3929814150842],[-99.1633779741792,19.3930471892216],[-99.1633676666966,19.3930905871479],[-99.1633539424123,19.3931484149288],[-99.1633536713463,19.393149556657],[-99.1633326516698,19.3932380913299],[-99.1633273408772,19.3932604765675],[-99.1633258846922,19.3932665988711],[-99.1632503982955,19.393250045508],[-99.1631580388255,19.3932297985256],[-99.1631022520036,19.3932175708424],[-99.1630096356198,19.3931972605697],[-99.1629243185542,19.3931785487074],[-99.1628253831388,19.3931568656532],[-99.1627721849032,19.3931451977826],[-99.1626860494573,19.3931263142213],[-99.1626865729325,19.3931240386763],[-99.162711364006,19.393124012126],[-99.1627524427473,19.3929332906781],[-99.1627565829766,19.3929140659265],[-99.1627814909565,19.3927984103957],[-99.1627980880081,19.3928020859532],[-99.1628764196311,19.3928194161424],[-99.1629163896067,19.3928282573258],[-99.1629931414886,19.3928452352628],[-99.1630458733238,19.3928569030601],[-99.1631201794492,19.3928733390959],[-99.1631648506849,19.3928832187645],[-99.1632414789013,19.3929001785344],[-99.1632705142618,19.3929065993979],[-99.1633527478204,19.3929247873036],[-99.1633697636313,19.3929285531163],[-99.1634043186724,19.3929362021363]]]]}`

I want to convert each one of these rows to a MultiPolygon in a GeoDataframe. I have tried passing each `str` to a `dict`, then to a `tuple` and from there try to create the GeoDataframe, but my guess is that there is a quicker way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have to create a **shapely geometry** by using *shape* function[1](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html?highlight=import%20shape#shapely.geometry.shape)

Secondly, you must use the [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html) library, specifying your **dataframe** and **geometry column**.

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import shape

# First step
df['geo_shape'] = shape({"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-99.1634043186724,19.3929362021363],[-99.1633935829153,19.3929814150842],[-99.1633779741792,19.3930471892216],[-99.1633676666966,19.3930905871479],[-99.1633539424123,19.3931484149288],[-99.1633536713463,19.393149556657],[-99.1633326516698,19.3932380913299],[-99.1633273408772,19.3932604765675],[-99.1633258846922,19.3932665988711],[-99.1632503982955,19.393250045508],[-99.1631580388255,19.3932297985256],[-99.1631022520036,19.3932175708424],[-99.1630096356198,19.3931972605697],[-99.1629243185542,19.3931785487074],[-99.1628253831388,19.3931568656532],[-99.1627721849032,19.3931451977826],[-99.1626860494573,19.3931263142213],[-99.1626865729325,19.3931240386763],[-99.162711364006,19.393124012126],[-99.1627524427473,19.3929332906781],[-99.1627565829766,19.3929140659265],[-99.1627814909565,19.3927984103957],[-99.1627980880081,19.3928020859532],[-99.1628764196311,19.3928194161424],[-99.1629163896067,19.3928282573258],[-99.1629931414886,19.3928452352628],[-99.1630458733238,19.3928569030601],[-99.1631201794492,19.3928733390959],[-99.1631648506849,19.3928832187645],[-99.1632414789013,19.3929001785344],[-99.1632705142618,19.3929065993979],[-99.1633527478204,19.3929247873036],[-99.1633697636313,19.3929285531163],[-99.1634043186724,19.3929362021363]]]]})
print(type(df)) # <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

# Second step
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geo_shape')
print(type(gdf)) # <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
```

- https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html?highlight=import%20shape#shapely.geometry.shape

Answer (score 1):

To create a shapely geometry, you can use `shape` function

```py
from shapely.geometry import shape

shape({"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-99.1634043186724,19.3929362021363],[-99.1633935829153,19.3929814150842],[-99.1633779741792,19.3930471892216],[-99.1633676666966,19.3930905871479],[-99.1633539424123,19.3931484149288],[-99.1633536713463,19.393149556657],[-99.1633326516698,19.3932380913299],[-99.1633273408772,19.3932604765675],[-99.1633258846922,19.3932665988711],[-99.1632503982955,19.393250045508],[-99.1631580388255,19.3932297985256],[-99.1631022520036,19.3932175708424],[-99.1630096356198,19.3931972605697],[-99.1629243185542,19.3931785487074],[-99.1628253831388,19.3931568656532],[-99.1627721849032,19.3931451977826],[-99.1626860494573,19.3931263142213],[-99.1626865729325,19.3931240386763],[-99.162711364006,19.393124012126],[-99.1627524427473,19.3929332906781],[-99.1627565829766,19.3929140659265],[-99.1627814909565,19.3927984103957],[-99.1627980880081,19.3928020859532],[-99.1628764196311,19.3928194161424],[-99.1629163896067,19.3928282573258],[-99.1629931414886,19.3928452352628],[-99.1630458733238,19.3928569030601],[-99.1631201794492,19.3928733390959],[-99.1631648506849,19.3928832187645],[-99.1632414789013,19.3929001785344],[-99.1632705142618,19.3929065993979],[-99.1633527478204,19.3929247873036],[-99.1633697636313,19.3929285531163],[-99.1634043186724,19.3929362021363]]]]})
```

For the whole DataFrame, you pass it to apply.

```py
geometry = df['your_column'].apply(shape)
```